# using $.get to get page content and render it into div tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to call page content using $.get method that will call a page(.ascx) and render page content into div in current page(aspx) i have used something like this... didin't work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calltemp1() {
  var result = '';
  $get("/Views/Templates/_Temp1.ascx",result)
  $("#RecentstoryDiv").html(result);
}
</script>
```

above script gives jscript runtime error "object expected".

Comment: Apart from anything else, it looks like you're missing a semi-colon on the second line of the function `calltemp1()`.

Answer (score 2):

use the load() function instead

```
$("#RecentstoryDiv").load('/Views/Templates/_Temp1.ascx');
```

See the documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback

Comment: thanks for reply 
i have tried above code but it produces following error
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

my partial "_Temp.ascx" page contents:
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/Temp1.ascx"); %>


does this has something to do with the error??
please reply

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be using [`$.get`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) and not `$get`
2. Your call to `$.get` is missing its ending semi-column
3. Second parameter to `$.get` is a callback, not a variable to be filled. You need to pass a function that will be passed the content as a parameter

Here is a working example:

```
$.get("/Views/Templates/_Temp1.ascx", function(result)
{
    $("#RecentstoryDiv").html(result);
});
```

But you will be better using the [`load`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) method

```
$("#RecentstoryDiv").load("/Views/Templates/_Temp1.ascx");
```

Comment: i have tried above example but it gives follwing error
" Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined "
what might be the reason .??
pls pls replay..

Comment: Can you add to your answer the code you are using to include jQuery in your page?